# Proving $\det AB = \det A \det B$ starting from the generalized eigenvalue definition?

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

I've been following the book Linear Algebra Done Right, and it's a good book, but I don't like how the subject of determinant is approached. So I tried to deduce the formula for the determinant on my own, but I hit a roadblock, as I need the property I asked for in the title, or something similar.

How would I go about doing this in a motivated way?

Comment: Small nitpick: there's no such thing as generalised eigenvalues, only eigenvalues, and (sometimes generalised) eigenvectors.

Comment: So, to be clear, you're reading the book, which defines determinants as the product of eigenvalues to the power of their multiplicities. What about the book's approach did you not like? Am I right in thinking that you still wish to use this definition of determinant?

Comment: @Theo You're right about the generalized eigenvector thing, my bad. Yes, I would like to keep this definition. What I did not like is how the explicit formula (sum over the permutations etc) was developed.

Comment: There is no easy way to derive the formula for $\det\left(AB\right)$ from the eigenvalue "definition". The eigenvalues of $AB$ usually have nothing to do with those of $A$ and of $B$. For example, it is easy to find two matrices $A$ and $B$ whose eigenvalues are rational while those of $AB$ are not. (Just take a generic matrix with irrational eigenvalues, and consider its LU decomposition.)

Comment: @Robly18 It's tricky to answer this without the book in front of me, let alone out-do Axler's approach. I quite like the eigenvalue definition too, but it does leave a gap between defining the determinant and actually using the determinant. I think maybe the most intuitive way to get from this definition to $\det(AB) = \det(A)\det(B)$ is using measure. Show that the image of a unit hypercube under $A$ has Lebesgue measure $\det(A)$. This connects most immediately with the geometry of eigenvectors. But, it's still a fair slog to get there.

Comment: @TheoBendit Maybe Axler will do that when he combines *Linear Algebra Done Right* and *Measure, Integration & Real Analysis* into the single highly anticipated *Multiple Things Done Strangely*.